# Number of different values per column in a split list

Tags: r, split, apply

Each row in my data set is a different tree. Plot refers to the sampling area (of which there are approx 700), Species is the species of the tree, and the other columns are whether the tree is present (1) or absent (NA). below is a minimal example of the data set

```
Plot    Species    1983    1988    2003    2008    2013
   1         11       1       1       1       1       1
   1         11       1       1       1       1      NA
   1         21      NA       1       1       1       1
   2         11       1       1       1       NA     NA
   2         34       1       1       1       1       1 
   3         15       1       1       1       1      NA
   3         15      NA       1       1       1      NA
   3         11       1       1       1       1      NA
```

Basically what I want to know is how many different species there are in each plot, each year, not including the NA values:

```
Plot        1983    1988    2003    2008    2013
   1           1       2       2       2       2
   2           2       2       2       1       1
   3           2       2       2       2       0
```

My current strategy was as follows - change all values of 1 into their species number so the data set looks as below

```
Plot    Species    1983    1988    2003    2008    2013
   1         11      11      11      11      11      11
   1         11      11      11      11      11      NA
   1         21      NA      21      21      21      21
   2         11      11      11      11      NA      NA
   2         34      34      34      34      34      34 
   3         15      15      15      15      15      NA
   3         15      NA      15      15      15      NA
   3         11      11      11      11      11      NA
```

and then split the data set according to the plot number using

```
split(data, as.factor(data$Plot))
```

I think i essentially want the length of each column to find out how many different values there are, but colSums doesnt account for the different plots. I am unsure how to use the apply functions when i have a split list.

Any suggestions welcome!
Thanks

Comment: I think `rowsum(df[-(1:2)], group=df$lot, na.rm=TRUE)` will do it, although it doesn't quite line up with your sums. For example, the third element of 1988 is 3 rather than 2.

Comment: @Imo that seems to work mostly, however it seems adding the actual values, rather than the number of different values present. The third element of 1988 should be 2 as there are two different species present (15 and 11)

Comment: @Henrik you are correct! apologies for the error there, will edit that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `tidyverse` approach:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  gather(Year, Value, na.rm = TRUE, -Plot, -Species) %>%
  group_by(Plot, Year) %>% 
  distinct(Species, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
  count(Plot, Year) %>% 
  spread(Year, n, fill = 0)

Source: local data frame [3 x 6]
Groups: Plot [3]

   Plot `1983` `1988` `2003` `2008` `2013`
* <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1      1      2      2      2      2
2     2      2      2      2      1      1
3     3      2      2      2      2      0
```

Comment: I like the method, something i haven't come across yet! however it seems to be adding the number of values, rather than the number of different species present - the last row in your output doesn't match my desired output.

Comment: Your desired output didn't agree with your data, which led me to thinking you wanted an overall count of all species present (see plot1 1988 with a value of 3 when 2 species are present).  I've included code for unique counts.

Comment: The second bit works perfectly for me, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

A couple of alternatives that calculate the same as the accepted answer. In base R using split-apply-combine method, you get

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df[-(1:2)] * df$Species, df$lot),
                      function(x) sapply(x, function(y) length(unique(y[!is.na(y)])))))
  X1983 X1988 X2003 X2008 X2013
1     1     2     2     2     2
2     2     2     2     1     1
3     2     2     2     2     0
```

This requires a nested loop. First, looping through the list of data.frames created by splitting on lot, then looping though each of the year variables. Here, `do.call` with `rbind` returns a matrix.

You can use `rbind.data.frame` with `setNames` to return a data.frame

```
setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(split(df[-(1:2)] * df$Species, df$lot),
                                         function(x) sapply(x,
                                                 function(y) length(unique(y[!is.na(y)]))))),
         names(df)[-(1:2)])

  X1983 X1988 X2003 X2008 X2013
1     1     2     2     2     2
2     2     2     2     1     1
3     2     2     2     2     0
```

In both of these, the lot is contained in the row names.

Then with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, lapply(.SD, function(x) length(unique((x * Species)[!is.na(x)]))),
  .SDcols=X1983:X2013, by=lot]
   lot X1983 X1988 X2003 X2008 X2013
1:   1     1     2     2     2     2
2:   2     2     2     2     1     1
3:   3     2     2     2     2     0
```

Comment: Not really. I was answering it simultaneously and it uses the logic from my base R solution.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) uniqueN(na.omit(x*Species))) , Plot, .SDcols = 3:7]
#   Plot 1983 1988 2003 2008 2013
#1:    1    1    2    2    2    2
#2:    2    2    2    2    1    1
#3:    3    2    2    2    2    0
```

---

Or a similar approach with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(Plot) %>%
    summarise_each(funs(n_distinct(na.omit(Species * .))), 3:7)
# A tibble: 3 × 6
#   Plot `1983` `1988` `2003` `2008` `2013`
#  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
#1     1      1      2      2      2      2
#2     2      2      2      2      1      1
#3     3      2      2      2      2      0
```